# Como passar o valor do EditText de um Fragment para o TextView de outro Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tenho um fragment que contém um EditText no qual o usuário irá digitar seu nome.

Em outro fragment está o TextView que irá receber o nome digitado no fragment anterior.

Fragment Editar (onde está o usuário digitará o nome):

```js
public class Editar extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{ 
    private EditText editar; private Button okBotao;

    View rootview;

    @Nullable 
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editar, container, false);

        editar = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editar); 
        okBotao = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ok);

        okBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                InicioActivity menu = new InicioActivity(); 
                Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
                args.putString("editar", editar.getText().toString());   
                menu.setArguments(args); 
            } 
         }); 
         return rootview;
    }
}
```

Fragment Início (onde o nome será exibido):

```js
public class Inicio extends Fragment { 
    TextView text; 
    View rootview;

    @Nullable 
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.campoNome);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        String editar = bundle.getString("editar");
        text.setText(editar);

        return rootview; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não fez a alteração ao `String.valueOf(editar)`. Que olhar para a pergunta vai pensar que esta é uma duplicata da outra e votará para fechar.

Comment: Eu alterei, mas mandei o código errado. Vou mandar o atualizado. Desculpe.

Comment: Não vejo como você manda exibir o Fragment inicio. No onClick cria uma instância dele, faz o `setArguments()` mas depois não faz mais nada.

Comment: Posso fazer isso com return menu? Mas aí eu teria que tirar o return rootview, não é?

Comment: Ou posso usar: [FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.container, menu);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();]   ?

Comment: Pode mas só na *Activity*. Julgo que a solução seria o método `onClick` chamar um método da *Activity* e por aí esse código. Quem deve controlar os *Fragments* deve ser a *Activity*.

Comment: Ah, então no caso uso dentro de onCreat ((MinhaActivity)getActivity()).nomeDoMétodo(); ?

Comment: No `onClick(View v)`. `((MinhaActivity)getActivity()).nomeDoMétodo(editar.getText().toString());`. Verifique se `getActivity()` não retorna null, não deve mas se retornar diga-me.

Comment: Neste momento não posso, mas mais tarde irei colocar uma resposta de como fazer isso de forma *"correta"*.

Comment: Muito obrigada por tudo. Vou tentar a última alteração que mandou.

Comment: Já tenho a resposta pronta mas, na altura que estava a revê-la, verifiquei que está a obter uma referência ao okBotao usando getActivity. O botão está no Fragment ou está na Activity? Se está na Activity tudo o que temos dito deixa de ter sentido.

Comment: O botão está no fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está com dificuldades porque está a atribuir responsabilidades ao *Fragment* ***Editar*** que não deviam ser dele.

O controlo dos *Fragments* associados a uma *Activity* é da responsabilidade desta.

Cada *Fragment* deve apenas se preocupar em gerir os seus dados/objectos.

O que você quer é que, quando um botão do *Fragment* *Editar* seja pressionado, o *Fragment* *Inicio* tenha a sua *TextView* actualizado com o texto que está no *EditText* do *Fragment* *Editar*.

Como a responsabilidade de gerir os *Fragments* é da *Activity* temos de arranjar uma forma de a notificar.
A forma de garantir que a *Activity* trata essa notificação é obrigar que ela implemente uma *interface* quando tenta associar o *Fragment* *Editar*.

Na classe *Editar* declaramos a *interface* a ser implementada e um campo para guardar uma referência a quem a implementar:

```
public class Editar extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private OnOkButtonListener mCallback;
    public interface OnOkButtonListener{
        //Métodos que a actividade devem implementar
        onOkButtonClick(string texto);
    }

    // É sempre bom ter um Context
    private Context context;
    ....
    ....
}
```

No método `onAttach()` verificamos se a *Activity*, que está a tentar associar o *Fragment*, implementa a *interface* e guardamos a sua referência:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    if(activity instanceof OnOkButtonListener){
        mCallback = (OnOkButtonListener) activity; //Guarda uma referência à actividade(interface)
    }
    else{
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                  + " A actividade deve implementar a interface OnOkButtonListener");
    }

    // No onAttach é o local mais seguro para se obter um Context
    context = activity; //Guarda context.

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Neste momento temos tudo o que precisamos para notificar a *Activity*.

Só falta fazer a notificação quando o botão é clicado:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editar, container, false);

    editar = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editar); 
    okBotao = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.ok);

    okBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            mCallback.onOkButtonClick(editar.getText().toString());
        } 
     }); 
     return rootview;
}
```

<sub>**Nota:**
Alterei a linha `okBotao = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ok);`

para `okBotao = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.ok);`

porque a resposta só faz sentido se o botão estiver no *Fragment Editar*, que é onde de fato deve estar.</sub>

O Fragment Inicio deverá ter um método público para alterar o seu TextView:

```
public void setTextViewText(String text){

    textView.setText(text);
}
```

Do lado da *Activity* temos que implementar a *interface*, declarando o método que será chamado pelo *Fragment*.
Como a Activity tem uma referência ao Fragment Inicio é só usá-la para chamar o seu método `setTextViewText()`:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity implements Editar.OnOkButtonListener{
    ...

    public void onOkButtonClick(string texto){

        //Código para actualizar o Fragment Inicio
        // Ou outra coisa qualquer
        fragmentInicio.setTextViewText(texto);
    }

    ......
}
```