# Passar dados entre fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Bom preciso do seguinte:
Tenho uma aplicação que te a`Acticity`essa é a principal e controla toda a aplicação, também tenho alguns `fragments`2 deles são interface outros 2 rodam em segundo plano.

A dúvida é a seguinte preciso passar dados do`FragmentA`para o `FragmentB`,só que no momento que tento fazer isso da erro, tentei orientar a `object`tentei `getter and setter`tentei `Bundle e intent`mas o erro persiste.

a idéia então é fazer o fragment1 passar dados pro fragment2 a activity principal contenua rodando normalmente em background.

alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Como assim "tentei orientar a object"? Que erro persiste?

Comment: Que tipo de dados quer passar? Em que altura os quer passar?

Comment: tento acessar um metodo que está em outro fragment(esses 2 fragments estao visiveis na tela) e ele me retorna um erro dizendo que nao pode acessar, tentei com thread e mesmo assim nao funcionou

Comment: Veja se [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58454/2541) ajuda, senão tem de dar mais detalhes sobre o que quer fazer.

Answer (score 3):

o Bundle so passa data para outro Fragment se o mesmo nao passou pelo attach .
Fragment nao se comunica diretamente com outro Fragment , o Fragment tem que se comunicar com a Activity e a Activity comunica com o Fragment B (isso se os 2 Fragments estiverem Up and running) , para isso vc tem q usar uma interface .

exemplo:

1) Interface

```
public interface OnCommunicateInterface
{
    void onSetText(String str);
}
```

2) MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnCommunicateInterface
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSetText(String str)
    {
        FragmentReceiveData f2 = (FragmentReceiveData) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_rec_data);
        f2.updateText(str);
    }
```

}

3) Fragment que vai enviar Data

```
public class FragmentSendData extends Fragment
{
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    OnCommunicateInterface onCommunicate;

    @Override
    /****************** onCreateView *****************/
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle b)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send_data,container,false);

        editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);

       View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               String str = editText.getText().toString();
               onCommunicate.onSetText(str);
           }
       };

       button.setOnClickListener(listener);

       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return (v);
    }

    @Override
    /**************** onAttach **************/
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try
        {
            onCommunicate = (OnCommunicateInterface) context;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("onAttach",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

4) Fragment que vai receber Data

```
public class FragmentReceiveData extends Fragment
{
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    /************** onCreateView() ******************/
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receive_data,container,false);

        textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return (v);
    }
    /*************** updateText() ********************/
    public void updateText(String string)
    {
        textView.setText(string);
    }
}
```

O cidogo esta meio feio , mas e pra ficar facil de entender e se trata de um exemplo simples.

espero que ajude .

Answer (score 2):

Fala Roger,

Pra passar dados entre os fragments, faça o seguinte, no momento que você for usar o FragmentMeneger você tem que criar um Bundle e passar junto, exemplo:

```
Fragment myFrag = new MyFragment();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("username", user_ame);
bundle.putString("senha", user_pass);
myFrag.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, myFrag).commit();
```

Abraços.

Comment: oi Leonardo, é o seguinte, o metodo bundle funciona caso eu for trocar a fragment, porém esses meus fragments eles já estao criados e em tempo de execução ou seja eles ja estão sendo mostrado na tela. também necessito chamar um ou mais metodos dentro de um fragment em determinado tempo, valeu a atenção

Answer (score 1):

Existem vários jeitos de fazer isto.

[Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
Armazena dados primitivos provados em pares chave-valor.

[Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)
Armazena dados privados na memória do dispositivo.

[SQLite Databases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
Armazena dados estruturados num banco de dados privado.

E também como o Leonardo Dias postou utilizando o Bundle.
Ai vai da sua utilidade e saber qual usar.