# Invocar Fragment dentro de Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou desenvolvendo um chat. Tenho uma MainActivity na qual invoco um fragment (que extend baseAdapter), onde listo todos os contactos numa listview. Ao clicar num contacto, pretendo abrir um novo fragmento que representara a janela de envio/recepção das sms.

O meu problema está em invocar o segundo fragment (dentro do onClickListener), será possível/correto invocar um fragment estando já dentro de um fragment? se sim, como poderei contornar esta situação?

Comment: A activity é que deve gerir os fragments. O fragment que tem a lista de contactos deve informar a activity que outro fragment deve ser aberto. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58454/2541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo de como resolver essa situação, levando em conta que como o Ramaral disse no comentário, a atividade é a responsável por trocar o fragmento ali dentro:

```
//Instancia o fragmentManager que é o responsável pela troca de Fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
//Instancia o fragment que você vai colocar na tela
Fragment fragment = new SeuFragment();
//Faz a transação, substituindo no frame da sua MainActivity que contem os fragmentos, o antigo pelo novo fragmento que você instanciou.
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_framelayout, fragment).commit();
```

Basicamente este é um jeito bem simples e genérico de trocar a tela a partir de um Fragment, lembre que se quiser passar alguma informação adiante, basta instanciar um `bundle` e seta-lo no fragment instanciado :)

Answer (score 0):

A resposta acima está correta, mas o código abaixo também funciona:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransacion = fragmentManager.beginTransacion();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_framelayout, fragment).commit();
```